# south: updating boolean field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

Say I have this model:

```
class Knight(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    of_the_round_table = models.BooleanField()
```

And Say I want to change it to this:

```
class Knight(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    round_table = models.BooleanField()
```

After `schemamigration southtut --auto --update` , South prompts me with the inevitable upon :

```
 ? The field 'Knight.of_the_round_table' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
 ? Since you are adding this field, you MUST specify a default
 ? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
 ?  1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
 ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
 ? Please select a choice: 2
 ? Please enter Python code for your one-off default value.
 ? The datetime module is available, so you can do e.g. datetime.date.today()
 >>> "True"
```

At the end of it all, when I tried to migrate with `./manage.py migrate someapp` I recieved this:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'True'
```

Not really sure why the "True" is incorrect. I believe I tried entering it without parenthesis and it gave that as well. What am I doing wrong here?  How should I enter a default value?

Edit:
Additional Question - why does south ask me to enter a value for each previous migration as well? If I migrated again and it changed the name of '`round_table`' to '`table`', it would ask me to set defaults for '`of_the_round_table = models.BooleanField()`', '`round_table = models.BooleanField()`', and '`table = models.BooleanField()`'. Why? Shouldn't it only ask for the latest one and is there anyway to make this process faster? I can see it being a pain if you have made many migrations in the past.

Comment: `"True"` is not a boolean value ... `True` is.  Not sure what you are talking about without parenthesis, you arent using any parenthesis.

Comment: hm, seems you are right. Another quick question, why does south ask me to enter a value for each previous migration as well? If I migrated again and it changed the name of 'round_table' to 'table', it would ask me to set defaults for 'of_the_round_table = models.BooleanField()', 'round_table = models.BooleanField()', and 'table = models.BooleanField()'. Why? Shouldn't it only ask for the latest one and is there anyway to make this process faster? I can see it being a pain if you have made many migrations in the past.

Comment: I have added this question to my original question, so feel free to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `"True"` is not a boolean value its a string.  Use `True`.
2. South can not only migrate forward, but backwards as well.  If migrating backwards it needs to know what values to put in the 'new' column `of_the_round_table`.  It may be easier to just specify defaults on your not null fields or better yet define your migration as a `rename_column` instead of a removing one column and adding another (as auto does for you).